# How to show domain masking subdomain htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain, url-masking

I have run into a wall. I need to show a domain name as the url but have it mask a sudomain. So here is the example:

```
http://es.mydomain.com (this is the content I need to show)
http://mydomain.com.mx (this is the url I need present)
```

They are both on the same hosting plan, I am not sure how to do this. The first domain: es.mydomain.com has a cname pointing to a translation service. I just need the second domain to mask it. If ANYONE could help that would be amazing. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain CNAMEs, but it is not a well-recognized practice.

Can you not just make a CNAME entry for `mydomain.com.mx` to the translation service directly, bypassing `es.mydomain.com`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I can not place cname directly, because it should have the es. infront of it to be able to recognize which language it needs to translate to. So this is my issue.. Any thoughts??

Comment: I also want to avoid duplicate content, so I need the english version to not be indexed.

Comment: A proxy server may be your best bet, and some translation services do work that way.